Weak acid + weak base titration calculation
I just wanted to know if the following question is even doable.

I've found the equilibrium constant of the neutralisation reaction ($K_aK_b/K_w$) which is just $4.45$ But I'm stuck trying to see what sort of assumptions the question wants me to make about X being the equivalence point. Because right now we have $6$ unknowns $(\ce{[NH3], [NH4+], [HBrO], [BrO-], [H3O+] and [OH-]}$) and we have $4$ equations ($K_a, K_b, K_w$ and $\ce{[HBrO] + [BrO] = 0.27}$M by mass balance of the amount of HBrO added). So I need to somehow get two more pieces of information out to solve the problem. Can anyone spot any reasonable assumptions I can make about the equivalence point that will make this question doable (if that is possible at all) thank you!

The choice of the base and acid is not the best. There is possibility of a redox side reaction .

Also, good luck in obtaining 0.45 M HBrO.

@Poutnik ignoring the rather shoddy question design and just following its intention, is there a way?

Closely related, bordering duplicate:  confusion-regarding-calculating-the-ph-of-a-salt-of-weak-acid-and-weak-base

Solving the problem via the set of equations is a universal method, but often unnecessarily complex. In this case, it is much better to focus on some approximations and on the task symmetry - approximate equality of ratios of concentrations of the respective conjugate pairs.
I am presenting two, slightly different methods:
First, the pH of the point of equivalence is equal to the pH of solution of the salt NH4BrO (objections from the comments aside). Note that the solution actions as a double pH buffer of systems $\ce{HBrO}$/$\ce{BrO-}$ and $\ce{NH3}$/$\ce{NH4+}$.
From
$$\ce{HBrO + NH3 <=> BrO- + NH4+},\tag{1}$$
we can assume
$$\frac{[\ce{BrO-}]}{[\ce{HBrO}]} \approx \frac{[\ce{NH4+}]}{[\ce{NH3}]}\tag{2}$$
with the approximation that concentrations of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ are much smaller than concentrations of the respective conjugate pair members.
Then we can apply Henderson–Hasselbalch equation that is just the logarithmic form of the equation for an acid dissociation equilibrium constant:
$$K_\text{a}=\dfrac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}$$
$$\text{pH} = \text{p}K_\text{a}(\ce{HBrO}) + \log {\left(\frac{[\ce{BrO-}]}{[\ce{HBrO}]}\right)}\tag{3}$$
$$\text{pH} = \text{p}K_\text{w} - \text{p}K_\text{b}(\ce{NH3}) + \log {\left(\frac{[\ce{NH3}]}{[\ce{NH4+}]}\right)}\tag{4}$$
Now we substiture the logarithm argument in (4) by the reciprocal value from the other side of (2) and accordingly change the logarithm sign:
$$\text{pH}=\text{p}K_\text{w} - \text{p}K_\text{b}(\ce{NH3}) - \log {\left(\frac{[\ce{BrO-}]}{[\ce{HBrO}]}\right)}\tag{5}$$
After summation of (3) and  (5) and dividing by 2:
$$\text{pH}=\frac{\text{p}K_\text{w} + \text{p}K_\text{a}(\ce{HBrO}) - \text{p}K_\text{b}(\ce{NH3})}{2}\tag{6}$$
$$\text{p}K_\text{w}=-\log{\pu{e-14}} = 14.00\tag{7}$$
$$\text{p}K_\text{a}(\ce{HBrO}) = -\log{\pu{2.50E-9}} \tag{8} \approx 8.60$$
$$\text{p}K_\text{b}(\ce{NH3}) = -\log{\pu{1.78E-5}} \tag{9} \approx 4.75$$
$$\text{pH}=\frac{14.00 + 8.60 - 4.75}{2} \approx 8.93 \tag{10}$$
As the resulting pH is very close to respective acidity constants of both conjugate pairs (8.6, 14-4.75=9.25) and considering the salt concentration, the requirement for the approximation is met.

The approach using the overall equilibrium constant
$$K = \frac{[\ce{BrO-}][\ce{NH4+}]}{[\ce{HBrO}][\ce{NH3}]} = \\
= \frac{[\ce{BrO-}][\ce{H+}]}{[\ce{HBrO}]} \cdot  \frac{[\ce{NH4+}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{NH3}]} \cdot  \frac{1}{[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]} = \frac{K_\text{a} \cdot K_\text{b}}{K_\text{w}} \tag{11}$$
can use the above approaximation (2), leading to the respective ratios being the square root of the constant. Involving (2) in (11), we get
$$K  \approx \left(\frac{[\ce{BrO-}]}{[\ce{HBrO}]}\right)^2 \tag{11a}$$
$$\log{K} = 2 \cdot \log{\left(\frac{[\ce{BrO-}]}{[\ce{HBrO}]}\right)} \tag{12}$$
$$ -\text{p}K_\text{a} -\text{p}K_\text{b} + \text{p}K_\text{w}= 2 \cdot (\text{pH} - \text{p}K_\text{a})\tag{13}$$
$$\text{pH}  = \frac{\text{p}K_\text{w} + \text{p}K_\text{a} - \text{p}K_\text{b}}{2} \tag{14}$$

Note that pH is close to pKa of both NH4+ and HBrO, solution near equivalence is the pH buffer and the titration detection would be very inaccurate.
